# C++ "everlasting" variable

Tags: c++

I need a variable which will contain the best player's score in C++ . So I need something which will not be erased after the program ends and every time when someone gets a higher score that variable must be replaced with a new one . I know that I can save that number in .txt file , but I would like to know if there is an alternative way ?

Comment: Text file (or other type of file), registry, web database. Those are pretty much the options.

Comment: saving the number is the key. you can save it anywhere you like. @chris I think you just mean a database not just limited to web databases?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Gee, if only computers had some way of, say, filing away information for future use...

Comment: Store it in the cloud. Or bettery yet, on The Internet. The Internet never forgets.

Comment: I’ve heard of a company called NSA which provides free online backups of your data …

Comment: @KonradRudolph: But I think that restoring your data from their backup isn't quite easy.

Comment: Nobody mention serialization?

Answer (score 6):

You could using something like [OpenKeyval](http://openkeyval.org/).

Setting the highscore would be a POST request:

```
$ curl http://api.openkeyval.org/highscore -d "data=1000"
```

Getting the highscore is a GET request:

```
$ curl http://api.openkeyval.org/highscore
1000
```

Comment: The score's 33400 now. Incrementing...

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to store it in a [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) database. That way you've got the flexibility of a database without needing to run or connect to a server.

Answer (score 0):

You have three main options that I can think of:
1.) Store it in a file
2.) Store it in the registry (http://forum.codecall.net/topic/63205-registry-operations-using-win32-part-1/)
3.) Store it on a server online that you can read or write to

Comment: Why do you assume that his platform actually has a registry but not a database? :)

Comment: I think that's not a general enough answer. They don't specify they are on windows. What about on a phone, linux, mac, embedded. Why must the server be online? The windows registry is also losing  favour and you should use an application data directory, per user.

Answer (score 0):

The most generic and "portable" way is to store it in a text file. Of course, that is also open to abuse, someone can open the file in notepad and change the score from 1234 to 999999, or similar.

Storing in a binary file will work, but is sensitive to machine architecture and size of the variable.

Windows has a "registry", which can be used to store strings or binary data, similar to files. But obviously won't work if you decide to move your game to Linux, for example.

If you want to keep track of all scores for all games played, a database may be a better solution than a simple file. There are databases for "local use", such as SQLite or MySql that you can run on your own machine (MySql will also run over network and can be centralized to a set of machines on the same network, and it used for a vast number of web-based applications).

And you could set up a (or use some existing) website, and use program driven web-access to store and restore the values. Or you could store a file on an FTP server, which is pretty much the same as web-access, but a little more "messing about" to configure and set up (and potentially more difficult to get through certain firewalls). Of course, if you want to have a "world-wide" top score, personal stats for each player, etc, then a web-based solution is probably the right way to go - but would also need a bit of security to prevent someone from just faking the score.

All choices have their benefits and drawbacks. Which is YOUR best choice really depends on what your ultimate goal is with your game. If it's simply a case of "Let's make a little game of tetris at home for myself and my friends to play", then it's probably not a big deal to keep the score in a text file. If you are looking for the next generation of World of Warcraft or some such, then web-based is almost certainly the ONLY solution.